# RMI Calculator Issue (JAVA)

Tags: java, client, rmi, calculator

I am coding an RMI Calculator program. I have created the following .java files. Following the guidelines, I came to the point where I have to run the service application. To do this I type

> start rmiregistry

and a new blank window opens. I then try to start the calculator service by typing the following:

> java CalculatorService

and then nothing happens.

My guidelines say that "I must ensure that I run the registry from the same directory as that in which the server is stored."

Do you think you could help me with this? 
Here's all my code:

Calculator.java

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Calculator extends java.rmi.Remote 
{ 
    /*
     * method for addition
     */ 
    public double add(double x, double y) 
            throws RemoteException;

    /*
     * method for subtraction 
     */ 
    public double subtract(double x, double y) 
            throws RemoteException; 
    /* 
     * method for multiplication
     */ 
    public double multiply(double x, double y) 
            throws RemoteException; 
    /* 
     * method for division 
     */ 
    public double divide(double x, double y) 
            throws RemoteException; 
}
```

RemoteCalculator.java

```
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject; 
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
public class RemoteCalculator extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Calculator
{
    public RemoteCalculator() throws RemoteException
    {

    } 

    /*
     * method for addition
     */ 
    public double add(double x, double y) 
    { 
        return x+y;
    }
    /* 
     * method for subtraction
     */ 
    public double subtract(double x, double y) 
    { 
        return x-y; 
    } 
    /*
     * method for multiplication 
     */ 
    public double multiply(double x, double y) 
    {
        return x*y; 
    }
    /* 
     * method for division 
     */ 
    public double divide(double x, double y)
    { 
        return x/y; 
    } 
}
```

CalculatorService.java

```
import java.rmi.Naming; 
import java.rmi.RemoteException; 
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;

public class CalculatorService 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException,java.net.MalformedURLException
    {
        RemoteCalculator remcalc = new RemoteCalculator(); 
        Naming.rebind("CalcService", remcalc); 

    }
}
```

CalculatorClient.java

```
import java.rmi.Naming; 
public class CalculatorClient 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        double x = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        try 
        { 
            //Connect to the calculator service 
            Calculator calc = (Calculator) Naming.lookup("rmi://" + args[0] + "/CalcService"); 
            System.out.println("Client bound: OK"); 
            //Add the numbers 
            System.out.println(x + " + " + y + " = " + calc.add(x, y)); 
            //Subtract the numbers 
            System.out.println(x + " - " + y + " = " + calc.subtract(x, y)); 
            //Multiply the numbers 
            System.out.println(x + " * " + y + " = " + calc.multiply(x, y)); 
            //Divide the numbers 
            System.out.println(x + " / " + y + " = " + calc.divide(x, y));

        } 
        catch (java.rmi.NotBoundException nbe) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Client bound: error: " + nbe); 
        }
        catch (java.net.MalformedURLException mue) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Client bound: error: " + mue); 

        } catch (java.rmi.RemoteException re)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *Nothing* happens? No exceptions? And what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps.

1. Compile using javac
2. compile with rmic compiler
3. start rmiregistry
4. start server
5. start client

Did you do the step2?

Comment: yes after I compiled RemoteCalculator.java I compiled it :
`rmic RemoteCalculator`